# POST call with application/octet-stream

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services

Hi I'm trying to trigger a POST call to the following [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236). and here's code

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString["returnFaceId"] = "true";
queryString["returnFaceLandmarks"] = "false";
queryString["returnFaceAttributes"] = "age,gender";

var filebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\IMG.jpg");

var uri = "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

HttpResponseMessage response;


using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(filebytes))
{
    response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I get the following error in `result`:

```
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"JSON parsing error."}}
```

This code works fine if I use `application/json`, and pass a http link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [example code given](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) by Microsoft, can you try to set `ContentType` like the sample :

```
using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
{
     content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("< your content type, i.e. application/json >");
     response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

Comment: For whom be using this with Azure Computer Vision API (OCR / Read), and posting a binary data (image), the line should be `content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");`

Answer (score 3):

Try to set request content type as "application/octet-stream".

Comment: isn't it set this way client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));?

Comment: _"Accept: is what the browser is able to digest, for example, all the languages someone can understand."_
_"Content-Type: is what format the actual data is in, for example what language someone is speaking. Since computers can't (well, now they can) recognize other types like people can say "oh, he's German!" or "she's speaking Chinese!""_

from [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers#31231)